# Why my app asks to choose to authenticate myself for my Rails app with HTTPS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl-certificate, thin

### Env

- Rails 4.0.4
- Using SSL certificates for HTTPS connections

In my `config/environments/production.rb`

```
# Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
config.force_ssl = true
```

This is how I start my server:

```
thin start -e production -d -p 3001 -P ./tmp/pids/thin_https.pid --ssl --ssl-key-file /etc/ssl/current/www_domain_io.key --ssl-cert-file /etc/ssl/current/WWW.DOMAIN.IO.crt
```

Then I am getting this screen when accessing my production website:

[image]

I click OK, and I land on my page https://www.domain.io page successfully. The entity is verified and the `https:` show in green. So I am good ... but why do I get that "Select a certificate to authenticate to www.domain.io:443` ? I figured that once my entity was verified I should land automatically on my page ? Any ideas?

### UPDATE

The documention shows `--ssl-disable-verify` option that is actually not available on `thin 1.6.2 codename Doc Brown`

```
   SSL options:
        --ssl                        Enables SSL
        --ssl-key-file PATH          Path to private key
        --ssl-cert-file PATH         Path to certificate
        --ssl-disable-verify         Disables (optional) client cert requests   <=== this is NOT available
```

I have posted an issue on [github](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/issues/244)

[Thin lighthouse ticket about --ssl-disable-verify](https://thin.lighthouseapp.com/projects/7212/changesets/85fdb1960039a7ed21ea3ad4badb49380493f11d)

[Existing ticket on GitHub](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/commit/85fdb1960039a7ed21ea3ad4badb49380493f11d)

I just don't understand how to get the version of thin where this option is available.

Answer (score 2):

A [similar post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354311/chrome-asks-to-select-a-certificate-for-ssl-on-my-rails-app-using-thin) suggests your `.crt` file includes the root CA certificate for your certificate chain. Remove it, and you should be good to go.

Intermediate certifcates should still remain in the `.crt` file, presumably.

Comment: I think I may be facing a thin issue here. There is an option `--ssl-disable-verify` in the doc, but `thin 1.6.2 codename Doc Brown` doesn't seem to have it. I am using the certs with `node.js` and it works well. Thx

Comment: mabako your suggestion doesn't seem to work. But thanks you for trying to help. Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You're starting your thin server on port 3001, but you're connecting to the regular https URL, which by default connects to port 443. So I assume you have a web server instance (Apache/nginx) proxying requests for thin.

If that's the case, you should disable SSL for thin, as this will be handled by the proxy server in front of your thin instance.

If you don't have a reverse proxy, and want to use just thin, you should specify the port where thin is listening in the URL (https://example.com:3001).

Comment: No Thin is taking care of the SSL stuff not using Apache or Nginx, although it looks like I will need to, if I can't resolve this thin issue.

Comment: Then you can't connect to port 443. When you write a `https` URL in your browser, it will always try to connect to that port. If you insist on letting thin handle SSL, which I wouldn't do, you have to connect to port 3001 as per my previous answer.

Comment: I am redirecting the 443 to 3001 with `iptables`. I do have it working fine, but it requests a client cert, which presumably can disable with `--ssl-disable-verify` on `thin`