# Verified Certificate with thin server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl-certificate, thin

I have one Trusted Certificate (.pfx extension) and I generate the .crt and .key files to use with Thin Server.

When I access the server the certificate don't work, still untrusted by chrome, I followed the instructions to use --ssl-cert-file and --ssl-key-file with thin server, what I'm doing wrong?

Sorry my bad english :/

Comment: Did you checked thin's logfile ? Did you enabled use of SSL ?

Comment: @JoanBlackmoore the command line used to run the server is thin start -p 12001 --ssl --ssl-cert-file certificate.crt --ssl-key-file certificate.key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check thin version, in older version this was the issue https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/issues/244
[Chrome asks to "Select a Certificate" for SSL on my Rails app using thin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354311/chrome-asks-to-select-a-certificate-for-ssl-on-my-rails-app-using-thin)

They have resolved it in new version https://rubygems.org/gems/thin/versions/2.0.0.pre

Comment: My version of thin server is _v1.6.3 codename Protein Powder_, I used in command line --ssl-disable-verify and the problem persist.

The version 2.0.0.pre in rubygems have the year correct?

Comment: @gumaro yes , as you can check with this article http://iswwwup.com/t/7caadb5c376f/chrome-asks-to-select-a-certificate-for-ssl-on-my-rails-app-using-thin.html

Comment: so the 2.0.0.pre is the only one can handle this bug with SSL?

Comment: have you tried 2.0.0 ?? have you check the article  I share in last comment ??